# slam_toolbox - Failed to compute odom pose (No map received in rviz)

Tags: ros2, rviz, slam, odometry, mapping

I'm trying to do mapping using slam toolbox and it's on a real robot. I don't have ros2 control since the supplier already provided the hardware interface with the robot launching file without a URDF. However, I added the urdf with robot state publisher launch file to visualize it on rviz and then I also added ekf filter so the odom is published to be see in rviz.

Now I am trying to use slam toolbox and facing this issue when I run:

```
ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py params_file:=./src/turn_on_dlrobot_robot/config/mapper_params_online_async.yaml use_sim_time:=false
```

Below are the codes with the TF tree, node graph and errors. Btw I'm using Jetson Orin Nano dev Kit running Jetpack 6 Ubuntu 22.04 with ROS2 Humble.

[image: RVIZ]
[image: Slam toolbox]
[image: rviz error]
[image: Node graph]
[image: Tf tree]

**This is the robot launch file:**

```
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, Command
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch.conditions import UnlessCondition
import launch_ros.actions
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource


def generate_launch_description():


  akmcar = LaunchConfiguration('akmcar', default='false')
  return LaunchDescription([
  
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'akmcar',
        default_value='false',
        description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true'),

    launch_ros.actions.Node(
        condition=IfCondition(akmcar),
        package='turn_on_dlrobot_robot', 
        executable='dlrobot_robot_node', 
        parameters=[{'usart_port_name': '/dev/ttyACM0',
            'serial_baud_rate': 115200,
            'robot_frame_id': 'base_link',
            'odom_frame_id': 'odom_combined',
            'cmd_vel': 'cmd_vel',
            'akm_cmd_vel': 'ackermann_cmd',
            'product_number': 0,}],
        remappings=[('/cmd_vel', 'cmd_vel'),]),

    launch_ros.actions.Node(
        condition=IfCondition(akmcar),
        package='turn_on_dlrobot_robot', 
        executable='cmd_vel_to_ackermann_drive.py', 
        name='cmd_vel_to_ackermann_drive',
        output='screen'),

    launch_ros.actions.Node(
        condition=UnlessCondition(akmcar),
        package='turn_on_dlrobot_robot', 
        executable='dlrobot_robot_node', 
        parameters=[{'usart_port_name': '/dev/ttyACM0',
            'serial_baud_rate': 115200,
            'robot_frame_id': 'base_link',
            'odom_frame_id': 'odom_combined',
            'cmd_vel': 'cmd_vel',
            'akm_cmd_vel': 'none',
            'product_number': 0,}],
        )

 ])
```

**Robot state publisher launch file**

```
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, Command
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node

import xacro


def generate_launch_description():

  # Check if we're told to use sim time
  use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')
  # use_ros2_control = LaunchConfiguration('use_ros2_control')


  # Process the URDF file
  pkg_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('turn_on_dlrobot_robot'))
  xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_path,'description','robot.urdf.xacro')
  # robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(xacro_file).toxml()
  robot_description_config = Command(['xacro ', xacro_file])


  # Create a robot_state_publisher node
  params = {'robot_description': robot_description_config, 'use_sim_time': 
  use_sim_time}
  node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
      package='robot_state_publisher',
      executable='robot_state_publisher',
      output='screen',
      parameters=[params]
  )


  # Launch!
  return LaunchDescription([
      DeclareLaunchArgument(
          'use_sim_time',
          default_value='false',
          description='Use sim time if true'),
      # DeclareLaunchArgument(
      #     'use_ros2_control',
      #     default_value='true',
      #     description='Use ros2_control if true'),

      node_robot_state_publisher
  ])
```

**ekf yaml file**

```
### ekf config file ###
ekf_filter_node:
ros__parameters:
    # The frequency, in Hz, at which the filter will output a position estimate. Note that the filter will not begin
    # computation until it receives at least one message from one of the inputs. It will then run continuously at the
    # frequency specified here, regardless of whether it receives more measurements. Defaults to 30 if unspecified.
    frequency: 30.0

    # The period, in seconds, after which we consider a sensor to have timed out. In this event, we carry out a predict
    # cycle on the EKF without correcting it. This parameter can be thought of as the minimum frequency with which the
    # filter will generate new output. Defaults to 1 / frequency if not specified.
    sensor_timeout: 0.1

    # ekf_localization_node and ukf_localization_node both use a 3D omnidirectional motion model. If this parameter is
    # set to true, no 3D information will be used in your state estimate. Use this if you are operating in a planar
    # environment and want to ignore the effect of small variations in the ground plane that might otherwise be detected
    # by, for example, an IMU. Defaults to false if unspecified.
    two_d_mode: false

    # Use this parameter to provide an offset to the transform generated by ekf_localization_node. This can be used for
    # future dating the transform, which is required for interaction with some other packages. Defaults to 0.0 if
    # unspecified.
    transform_time_offset: 0.0

    # Use this parameter to provide specify how long the tf listener should wait for a transform to become available. 
    # Defaults to 0.0 if unspecified.
    transform_timeout: 0.0

    # If you're having trouble, try setting this to true, and then echo the /diagnostics_agg topic to see if the node is
    # unhappy with any settings or data.
    print_diagnostics: true

    # Debug settings. Not for the faint of heart. Outputs a ludicrous amount of information to the file specified by
    # debug_out_file. I hope you like matrices! Please note that setting this to true will have strongly deleterious
    # effects on the performance of the node. Defaults to false if unspecified.
    debug: false

    # Defaults to "robot_localization_debug.txt" if unspecified. Please specify the full path.
    debug_out_file: /path/to/debug/file.txt

    # Whether we'll allow old measurements to cause a re-publication of the updated state
    permit_corrected_publication: false

    # Whether to publish the acceleration state. Defaults to false if unspecified.
    publish_acceleration: false

    # Whether to broadcast the transformation over the /tf topic. Defaults to true if unspecified.
    publish_tf: true

    # REP-105 (http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) specifies four principal coordinate frames: base_link, odom, map, and
    # earth. base_link is the coordinate frame that is affixed to the robot. Both odom and map are world-fixed frames.
    # The robot's position in the odom frame will drift over time, but is accurate in the short term and should be
    # continuous. The odom frame is therefore the best frame for executing local motion plans. The map frame, like the odom
    # frame, is a world-fixed coordinate frame, and while it contains the most globally accurate position estimate for your
    # robot, it is subject to discrete jumps, e.g., due to the fusion of GPS data or a correction from a map-based
    # localization node. The earth frame is used to relate multiple map frames by giving them a common reference frame.
    # ekf_localization_node and ukf_localization_node are not concerned with the earth frame.
    # Here is how to use the following settings:
    # 1. Set the map_frame, odom_frame, and base_link frames to the appropriate frame names for your system.
    #     1a. If your system does not have a map_frame, just remove it, and make sure "world_frame" is set to the value of
    #         odom_frame.
    # 2. If you are fusing continuous position data such as wheel encoder odometry, visual odometry, or IMU data, set
    #   "world_frame" to your odom_frame value. This is the default behavior for robot_localization's state estimation nodes.
    # 3. If you are fusing global absolute position data that is subject to discrete jumps (e.g., GPS or position updates
    # from landmark observations) then:
    #     3a. Set your "world_frame" to your map_frame value
    #     3b. MAKE SURE something else is generating the odom->base_link transform. Note that this can even be another state
    #         estimation node from robot_localization! However, that instance should *not* fuse the global data.
    # map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
    odom_frame:  odom           # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
    base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
    world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

    # The filter accepts an arbitrary number of inputs from each input message type (nav_msgs/Odometry,
    # geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped, geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovarianceStamped,
    # sensor_msgs/Imu). To add an input, simply append the next number in the sequence to its "base" name, e.g., odom0,
    # odom1, twist0, twist1, imu0, imu1, imu2, etc. The value should be the topic name. These parameters obviously have no
    # default values, and must be specified.
    odom0: odom_combined

    # Each sensor reading updates some or all of the filter's state. These options give you greater control over which
    # values from each measurement are fed to the filter. For example, if you have an odometry message as input, but only
    # want to use its Z position value, then set the entire vector to false, except for the third entry. The order of the
    # values is x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw, ax, ay, az. Note that not some message types
    # do not provide some of the state variables estimated by the filter. For example, a TwistWithCovarianceStamped message
    # has no pose information, so the first six values would be meaningless in that case. Each vector defaults to all false
    # if unspecified, effectively making this parameter required for each sensor.
    odom0_config: [true,  true,  false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, true,
                   false, false, false]

    # If you have high-frequency data or are running with a low frequency parameter value, then you may want to increase
    # the size of the subscription queue so that more measurements are fused.
    odom0_queue_size: 2

    # [ADVANCED] When measuring one pose variable with two sensors, a situation can arise in which both sensors under-
    # report their covariances. This can lead to the filter rapidly jumping back and forth between each measurement as they
    # arrive. In these cases, it often makes sense to (a) correct the measurement covariances, or (b) if velocity is also
    # measured by one of the sensors, let one sensor measure pose, and the other velocity. However, doing (a) or (b) isn't
    # always feasible, and so we expose the differential parameter. When differential mode is enabled, all absolute pose
    # data is converted to velocity data by differentiating the absolute pose measurements. These velocities are then
    # integrated as usual. NOTE: this only applies to sensors that provide pose measurements; setting differential to true
    # for twist measurements has no effect.
    odom0_differential: false

    # [ADVANCED] When the node starts, if this parameter is true, then the first measurement is treated as a "zero point"
    # for all future measurements. While you can achieve the same effect with the differential paremeter, the key
    # difference is that the relative parameter doesn't cause the measurement to be converted to a velocity before
    # integrating it. If you simply want your measurements to start at 0 for a given sensor, set this to true.
    odom0_relative: false

    # [ADVANCED] Whether to use the starting pose of child_frame_id as the origin of odometry.
    # Note: this is different from setting odom0_relative to true, as when child_frame is different from 
    # base_link_frame, the rotation of base_link will be coupled into the translation of child_frame.
    # Set to true for fusing secondary odometry sources that are rigidly connected to base_link but has a non-zero 
    # offset from base_link.
    odom0_pose_use_child_frame: false

    # [ADVANCED] If your data is subject to outliers, use these threshold settings, expressed as Mahalanobis distances, to
    # control how far away from the current vehicle state a sensor measurement is permitted to be. Each defaults to
    # numeric_limits<double>::max() if unspecified. It is strongly recommended that these parameters be removed if not
    # required. Data is specified at the level of pose and twist variables, rather than for each variable in isolation.
    # For messages that have both pose and twist data, the parameter specifies to which part of the message we are applying
    # the thresholds.
    odom0_pose_rejection_threshold: 5.0
    odom0_twist_rejection_threshold: 1.0

    # Further input parameter examples
    odom1: example/odom2
    odom1_config: [false, false, true,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, true,
                   false, false, false]
    odom1_differential: false
    odom1_relative: true
    odom1_queue_size: 2
    odom1_pose_rejection_threshold: 2.0
    odom1_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.2
    pose0: example/pose
    pose0_config: [true,  true,  false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false]
    pose0_differential: true
    pose0_relative: false
    pose0_queue_size: 5
    pose0_rejection_threshold: 2.0  # Note the difference in parameter name

    twist0: example/twist
    twist0_config: [false, false, false,
                    false, false, false,
                    true,  true,  true,
                    false, false, false,
                    false, false, false]
    twist0_queue_size: 3
    twist0_rejection_threshold: 2.0

    imu0: mobile_base/sensors/imu_data
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  true,  true,  true]
    imu0_differential: false
    imu0_relative: true
    imu0_queue_size: 5
    imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 # Note the difference in parameter names
    imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                #
    imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  #

    # [ADVANCED] Some IMUs automatically remove acceleration due to gravity, and others don't. If yours doesn't, please set
    # this to true, and *make sure* your data conforms to REP-103, specifically, that the data is in ENU frame.
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    # [ADVANCED]  The EKF and UKF models follow a standard predict/correct cycle. During prediction, if there is no
    # acceleration reference, the velocity at time t+1 is simply predicted to be the same as the velocity at time t. During
    # correction, this predicted value is fused with the measured value to produce the new velocity estimate. This can be
    # problematic, as the final velocity will effectively be a weighted average of the old velocity and the new one. When
    # this velocity is the integrated into a new pose, the result can be sluggish covergence. This effect is especially
    # noticeable with LIDAR data during rotations. To get around it, users can try inflating the process_noise_covariance
    # for the velocity variable in question, or decrease the  variance of the variable in question in the measurement
    # itself. In addition, users can also take advantage of the control command being issued to the robot at the time we
    # make the prediction. If control is used, it will get converted into an acceleration term, which will be used during
    # predicition. Note that if an acceleration measurement for the variable in question is available from one of the
    # inputs, the control term will be ignored.
    # Whether or not we use the control input during predicition. Defaults to false.
    use_control: true

    # Whether the input (assumed to be cmd_vel) is a geometry_msgs/Twist or geometry_msgs/TwistStamped message. Defaults to
    # false.
    stamped_control: false

    # The last issued control command will be used in prediction for this period. Defaults to 0.2.
    control_timeout: 0.2

    # Which velocities are being controlled. Order is vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw.
    control_config: [true, false, false, false, false, true]

    # Places limits on how large the acceleration term will be. Should match your robot's kinematics.
    acceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]

    # Acceleration and deceleration limits are not always the same for robots.
    deceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]

    # If your robot cannot instantaneously reach its acceleration limit, the permitted change can be controlled with these
    # gains
    acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]

    # If your robot cannot instantaneously reach its deceleration limit, the permitted change can be controlled with these
    # gains
    deceleration_gains: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

    # [ADVANCED] The process noise covariance matrix can be difficult to tune, and can vary for each application, so it is
    # exposed as a configuration parameter. This matrix represents the noise we add to the total error after each
    # prediction step. The better the omnidirectional motion model matches your system, the smaller these values can be.
    # However, if users find that a given variable is slow to converge, one approach is to increase the
    # process_noise_covariance diagonal value for the variable in question, which will cause the filter's predicted error
    # to be larger, which will cause the filter to trust the incoming measurement more during correction. The values are
    # ordered as x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw, ax, ay, az. Defaults to the matrix below if
    # unspecified.
    # Note: the specification of covariance matrices can be cumbersome, so all matrix parameters in this package support
    # both full specification or specification of only the diagonal values.
    process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.05, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.025, 0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.025, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.04, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.015]

    # [ADVANCED] This represents the initial value for the state estimate error covariance matrix. Setting a diagonal
    # value (variance) to a large value will result in rapid convergence for initial measurements of the variable in
    # question. Users should take care not to use large values for variables that will not be measured directly. The values
    # are ordered as x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw, ax, ay, az. Defaults to the diagonal values below
    # if unspecified. In this example, we specify only the diagonal of the matrix.
    initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9]
```

**mapper_params_online_async**

```
slam_toolbox:
 ros__parameters:

  # Plugin params
  solver_plugin: solver_plugins::CeresSolver
  ceres_linear_solver: SPARSE_NORMAL_CHOLESKY
  ceres_preconditioner: SCHUR_JACOBI
  ceres_trust_strategy: LEVENBERG_MARQUARDT
  ceres_dogleg_type: TRADITIONAL_DOGLEG
  ceres_loss_function: None

  # ROS Parameters
  odom_frame: odom
  map_frame: map
  base_frame: base_footprint
  scan_topic: /scan
  use_map_saver: true
  mode: mapping #localization

  # if you'd like to immediately start continuing a map at a given pose
  # or at the dock, but they are mutually exclusive, if pose is given
  # will use pose
  #map_file_name: test_steve
  # map_start_pose: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
  #map_start_at_dock: true

  debug_logging: false
  throttle_scans: 1
  transform_publish_period: 0.02 #if 0 never publishes odometry
  map_update_interval: 5.0
  resolution: 0.05
  max_laser_range: 20.0 #for rastering images
  minimum_time_interval: 0.5
  transform_timeout: 0.2
  tf_buffer_duration: 30.0
  stack_size_to_use: 40000000 #// program needs a larger stack size to serialize 
  large maps
  enable_interactive_mode: true

  # General Parameters
  use_scan_matching: true
  use_scan_barycenter: true
  minimum_travel_distance: 0.5
  minimum_travel_heading: 0.5
  scan_buffer_size: 10
  scan_buffer_maximum_scan_distance: 10.0
  link_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.1  
  link_scan_maximum_distance: 1.5
  loop_search_maximum_distance: 3.0
  do_loop_closing: true 
  loop_match_minimum_chain_size: 10           
  loop_match_maximum_variance_coarse: 3.0  
  loop_match_minimum_response_coarse: 0.35    
  loop_match_minimum_response_fine: 0.45

  # Correlation Parameters - Correlation Parameters
  correlation_search_space_dimension: 0.5
  correlation_search_space_resolution: 0.01
  correlation_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.1 

  # Correlation Parameters - Loop Closure Parameters
  loop_search_space_dimension: 8.0
  loop_search_space_resolution: 0.05
  loop_search_space_smear_deviation: 0.03

  # Scan Matcher Parameters
  distance_variance_penalty: 0.5      
  angle_variance_penalty: 1.0    

  fine_search_angle_offset: 0.00349     
  coarse_search_angle_offset: 0.349   
  coarse_angle_resolution: 0.0349        
  minimum_angle_penalty: 0.9
  minimum_distance_penalty: 0.5
  use_response_expansion: true
```

Comment: Please post the console output of your `ros launch ...` as code formatted text. Screenshots of text are not text searchable, nor particularly easy to read, and impossible to copy. Thanks. Apart from that, this *looks* like a good question. :-)